# angular 2 generic click event in child component

Tags: angular

There is a child component which is used in many pages of an angular web app. The child component has a `(click)` event which calls a function. Each page that consist of this child component is calling a different function with different parameters on click event.

How can I make this `(click)` event generic or dynamic that it calls the different function if the parent is different?

```
// In one component    
(click)="saveData(types, functions)"

// On another component
(click)="showFunctions(index, areas, types)"
```

Using a single child component in multiple pages with different click event, how we can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, because I am passing some data through arguments from the child component. So in order to pass it to the higher component, I am using eventEmmiter.

Comment: Output and Input will be able to help you achieve this. Or EventEmitter like the answer below

Answer (score 12):

Child:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onMyClick()">Click<button>

@Output() myClick = new EventEmitter();

onMyClick() {
    this.myClick.emit();
}
```

Parent:

```
<my-child-cmp (myClick)="firstFunction()"></my-child-cmp>

firstFunction() {
   // whatever
}
```

Parent2:

```
<my-child-cmp (myClick)="secondFunction()"></my-child-cmp>

secondFunction() {
   // whatever
}
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need more details.

**By the way if you need to send some data from child to your parent you can do smth like this:**

Child:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onMyClick()">Click<button>

@Output() myClick = new EventEmitter();

onMyClick() {
    this.myClick.emit(something);
}
```

Parent:

```
<my-child-cmp (myClick)="firstFunction($event)"></my-child-cmp>

firstFunction(event: Event) {
   console.log(event); // You will see something here))

}
```

**UPDATE:**

**If we need send data from parent to child**

Parent

```
data: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = 'hello world';
}

<app-child [settings]="data"></app-child>
```

Child:

```
@Input() settings: any;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.settings);
}
```

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if we need send similar event from parent to child??